# Corda mapping entity with collection column

Tags: hibernate, corda

According to the latest docs [Persistence](https://docs.corda.net/releases/release-V3.1/api-persistence.html)

I cannot find how to map java collection like List, Set.. 
Does it possible to store Set to the schema?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at `SampleCashSchemaV3.kt`, here: https://github.com/corda/corda/blob/release-V3/finance/src/test/kotlin/net/corda/finance/schemas/SampleCashSchemaV3.kt.

In this schema, the list of participants is stored as a `MutableSet<AbstractParty>?`:

```
object SampleCashSchemaV3 : MappedSchema(schemaFamily = CashSchema.javaClass, version = 3,
        mappedTypes = listOf(PersistentCashState::class.java)) {
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "cash_states_v3")
    class PersistentCashState(
            /** [ContractState] attributes */

            /** X500Name of participant parties **/
            @ElementCollection
            var participants: MutableSet<AbstractParty>? = null,

            /** X500Name of owner party **/
            @Column(name = "owner_name")
            var owner: AbstractParty,

            @Column(name = "pennies")
            var pennies: Long,

            @Column(name = "ccy_code", length = 3)
            var currency: String,

            /** X500Name of issuer party **/
            @Column(name = "issuer_name")
            var issuer: AbstractParty,

            @Column(name = "issuer_ref", length = MAX_ISSUER_REF_SIZE)
            @Type(type = "corda-wrapper-binary")
            var issuerRef: ByteArray
    ) : PersistentState()
}
```